# Programatically Add user to a SharePoint Group C# CSOM SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, groups

I am trying to programatically add user to a SharePoint Group. 
I have a function that takes two values: userName and groupName.

I am able to pass a groupName and the function does input AD group user into provided group right now i am able to pass 
User member = web.EnsureUser(@"sp2013\testuser1"); -- SP user
if i try to replace member by string 
string member = "nonaduser"; then  group.Users.AddUser(member); booms

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AddUsersInGroup("abc", "abcgroup");
    }
    static void clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    static void AddUsersInGroup(string username, string groupName)
    {
        if (username != null && groupName != null)
        {
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp2013/");
            clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest;
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            User member = web.EnsureUser(@"sp2013\testuser1"); 
            GroupCollection groupCollection = web.SiteGroups;

            clientContext.Load(groupCollection);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (Group group in groupCollection)
            {
                if (group.Title.Equals(groupName))
                {
                    group.Users.AddUser(member);
                    group.Update();
                    web.Update();
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code isn't clear, and it misses the most important part in AddUsersInGroup.
What do you do with username variable?
Also: does your web application uses claims authentication?

Comment: username variable is the logged in user and this user is a FBA user sitting in a user table on sql server  ,it is not a AD group and yes I am using Claims authentication/forms authentication

Comment: I guessed so, but would be better if you modify the question to include that.
So you must convert the username into claim, as explained http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401391/encoded-login-names-in-sharepoint-client-object-model
  Please also include the part adding user to group in your code posted, to make the question meaningful

Comment: What's the problem here? Are you getting an error? If so, add the error details.

Comment: in the case of forms authentication. you should use the userinfo as below. I have included regular object model but you can easily convert it in to CSOM
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            string userName = "i:0#.f|aspnetsqlmembershipprovider|forms_user";
                            web.SiteUsers.Add(userName, null, null, null);
                            web.Update();                            
                        }

Comment: i did not mention on how to add the logged in FBA user. You have mentioned the user name is not an AD  which is FBA user. so the format to add the FBA user should be "i:0#.f|aspnetsqlmembershipprovider|forms_user" in SP 2010 sites

Comment: @user17970, please update your question with this info.  It's difficult to dig through comments for this information.